# How to restrict user from viewing specific article by category?

Tags: permissions, knowledge

I have article knowledge enabled in my org and I would like to do some restriction that some users only able to see certain articles by category.

I have created a few category group and my 'Default Visibility Settings' set to None but my standard user still able to see published article and the category.

Am i missing anything here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> If a user has a role, the data category visibility settings for that role determine the user's access to categories.
>
> Users without roles can access categories as defined in default settings.

Following points you can check to figure the root cause

1)Whats the Role of the User?

If user has role then data category set up for role decides visibility else default visibility

2)Does your user has view All?If view All is set then the user has full access to view the article

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=category_visibility_modify.htm&siteLang=en_US

Comment: My user is a normal agent role who report to team leader and report to head of department. this user profile does not have view all access as well

Answer (score 0):

Data Category Visibility is driven by:
 - Role or default if no role
and 
 - Profile / Permission Set